# Using WebComponent to Include a react app in an angularjs App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, iframe

We have a legacy code written in Angular JS 1.x. We have decided to go with ReactJS for new feature and over the course of time migrate the whole app to React. 
Lets say App1 which is primary app is in Angular and App2 in React. On a button click we have to load App2 in an overlay(modal or a page) and after closing App2 it should update a counter on App1.

I can load  App2 in iframe (But not sure weather its a right approach).
I also read that you could do the same thing with Webcomponents. But since its the same DOM will react and AngularJS coexist ?

Many people suggest using ngReact but the scope of App2 is going to grow over time and will have a lot of independent code. Hence I feel keeping a separate App is a better idea so I dont need to worry about the build system and other overheads.

Comment: If you ask me, It's much better if you replace the page with your apps instead open `iframe` in same page, use simple `href` to change the `apps`.

Comment: But if you use a common `params` in both apps `AngularJs` & `React` try to pass them on new `url`, but as you say `iframe` it's not good idea

Comment: But what if there is a back and forth between the apps. Wont it be expensive to reload App1 all the time? Considering the primary app is in angular and is quite heavy

Comment: In this case i have to say it's totally wrong decision to using two different framework which you know the expensive!... but maybe there is a way to do it my friend knowledge is nonstop.

Comment: Well changing legacy code will take a whole lot of time and new features cant be stopped so rewrite will eventually happen hence that kind of decision. Bandwidth etc are other issues as well.